# postgresql pg_ctl start timed out

Tags: postgresql, centos7, postgresql-9.2

My system is running on CentOS 7.4 and we used systemd service to start the postgresql 9.2.21 server. postgresql is started by the following commands:

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA}
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -o "-p ${PGPORT}" -w -t 300 -l /tmp/log
```

pg_ctl returned start timed out intermittently. It failed with "postgresql.service start operation timed out." error.  Running **systemctl status postgresql** showed the following:

```
â postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Thu 2020-02-13 15:57:02 PST; 52s ago
  Process: 1098 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -o -p ${PGPORT} -w -t 300 -l /tmp/log (code=killed, signal=TERM)
  Process: 1021 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 13 23:52:02 server systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
Feb 13 23:52:03 server pg_ctl[1098]: pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
Feb 13 15:57:02 server systemd[1]: postgresql.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Feb 13 15:57:02 server systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
Feb 13 15:57:02 server systemd[1]: Unit postgresql.service entered failed state.
Feb 13 15:57:02 server systemd[1]: postgresql.service failed.
```

The output logs of the pg_ctl:

```
2020-02-13 23:52:05 UTC LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-02-13 23:49:55 UTC
2020-02-13 23:52:21 UTC LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2020-02-13 23:52:21 UTC LOG:  record with zero length at 0/1CEDFD8
2020-02-13 23:52:21 UTC LOG:  redo is not required
2020-02-13 23:52:21 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2020-02-13 23:52:21 UTC LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2020-02-13 23:57:02 UTC LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2020-02-13 23:57:02 UTC LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2020-02-13 23:57:02 UTC LOG:  shutting down
2020-02-13 23:57:03 UTC LOG:  database system is shut down
```

The above log showed the database was started up successfully and I actually could sql to the database until the database was shutdown by pg_ctl.  According to the pg_ctl manpage, it will repeatedly attempts to connect to the server. I wonder why pg_ctl cannot connect to the server and exit but I can manually do that during the startup.

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: Seems another Postgres process is running on the same port: `Feb 13 23:52:03 server pg_ctl[1098]: pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway`. Can you do a `netstat -nlp` and see if some other process is listening on the port you intended to run Postgres on? And a `ps -ef` to see if another Postgres process is running?

Comment: @richyen You mean "another PostgreSQL process was already started in the same directory", not "was started on the same port", right? This message is caused by a `postgresql.pid` file left behind in the data directory.

Comment: Right, my mistake

Comment: `pg_ctl` does not stop the server unless you explicitly tell it to. I would look for the problem in systemd. By the way, **don't** use version 9.2. For one, you cannot expect good support for a version as old as that.